# Terraform: Add resource-specific secrets

Tags: terraform

I know that you can pass general secrets to a resource through terraform variables. Is there a way to configure secrets which change at the resource level?

Specifically, I'm using terraform as a back-end to an app which allows users to set up a server with a password. That password is different for each server. Is there some way to set something like `self.password` for a single instance so that it:

1. Is not visible in the github repo where I track the terraform files

and

2. Can be changed for each individual instance

Right now I'm just going to be creating terraform files like `password=var.{unique_id}_password` but if feels like there should be a better way

#### More detail on the use-case:

I have a web application to provision servers for users running another web app. The password for that server is set-up by my application. The password is configured right now using a set-up script that I would like to port to terraform.

The passwords change for each server because a user can set the password for their server only, and that variable should not effect other resources

Here's a super-simplified version of the expected output when a user tries to provision a server

```
# new-server.tf
resource "digitalocean_droplet" "new_server" {
   name = "new_server"
   password = "${var.get_the_password_somehow}"

   provisioner "remote-exec" {
    inline = [
      "set-password ${self.password}"
    ]
  }
}
```

Comment: Can you clarify what you mean by **Can be changed for each individual instance**? I am confused about your end goal. Maybe illustrate more where the secret data currently comes from and how you assign them to resources.

Comment: Sure: The short version is that the infrastructure is provisioned dynamically from a web application where users can set the password via a web form. Then that password is used in a set-up script when provisioning the resource. Updating the post now with more detail

Comment: FWIW: I know the other potentially solution is to have some server-side secret and then to send the password via an API call to the other server, authenticated via that secret. But would prefer to utilize terraform if possible

Comment: How are you going to be calling the Terraform configurations?  If it's a server-side script executed by your web app you should be able to ask the user for a password and then pass it to the config on execution with var="password=<user_input>"

Comment: You can't use a variable `terraform apply -var="password=abcd123"` ?

Comment: I want the password to be different for different resources in a way that's dynamic. i.e. If I have `resource "digitalocean_droplet" "r1"` and `resource "digitalocean_droplet" "r2"` I want to be able to have a variable I can reference like `r1.password` and `r2.password` for each of them

Answer (score 0):

You can use the random_password provider to generate a random string. 
Reference: https://www.terraform.io/docs/providers/random/r/password.html

Not sure if your use case requires management or storage of the password, but that is also possible depending on your needs. I see that you are using DO for provisioning resources.

Maybe you can put Hashicorp Vault in place to manage the randomly generated passwords. I'm an AWS guy so I would stick the password in secrets manager.

Comment: Hmm, not quite what I'm looking for since I want users to be able to provide the password. Can I integrate vault for that?

Comment: I see, read the comments and if the user is supplying a password you need pass that to your automation provisioning stack. You are collecting it in a webform, does it get stored somewhere? Maybes stick in DynamoDB and create a data source in TF to read the Dynamo UID/Pass information.